# Intellij Idea Community Edition, cannot set `Gradle home`

Tags: java, intellij, gradle

I installed Gradle from the repository. Then I downloaded Intellij Idea Community Edition from the official website and installed it.

I set the Java JDK and now I am trying to open a Gradle Project, but the problem is that it doesn't accept my Gradle home:

[image]

```
~/Documents/idea-IC-141.2735.5/bin$ whereis gradle
gradle: /usr/bin/gradle /usr/share/gradle /usr/share/man/man1/gradle.1.gz
```

What's wrong?

Edit: now I can choose the first option `Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`

Probably because I restarted, I don't know

Comment: What is IntellIJ says when it doesn't accept ? Any alert or error message. *Add this information to your answer because the problem is not obvious from screenshot that you attached*

Comment: You are right, I substituted the screenshot

Comment: Did you tried my suggestion? Please give me response on my answer. *If it will be unhelpful for you I just remove it.*

Comment: Not yet, RL priorities came in, I'll tell you asap

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `Gradle home` option you need provide path to folder where your Gradle distribution was installed.

To determine the Gradle home location of your Gradle installation:

1. Create build.gradle containing:

   ```
   task getHomeDir << {
       println gradle.gradleHomeDir
   }
   ```
2. Run

   ```
   gradle getHomeDir
   ```

Reference: [Setting up Gradle Plugin For IntelliJ](http://web.archive.org/web/20160305074342/http://www.rabblemedia.net/blog/setting-up-gradle-plugin-for-intellij/)

Comment: I get `21.26.31: Executing external task 'getHomeDir'...
:getHomeDir
/home/elect/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.2-all/1vevkra640w3rb9hkuw50q5we/gradle-2.2` it seems it falls back using the default gradle wrapper

Comment: @elect So anyway did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Just by selecting "use default gradle wrapper"..

Comment: The step linked works. Just make sure to not have a space at the end.

Comment: in Gradle 5.4.1 I get error "Could not find method leftShift() for arguments [build_a40fhrzx78ylj5i2p6fgsmqo4$_run_closure3@2ece1ad3] on task ':getHomeDir' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask." - it may be resolved by removing the `<<`